# How to get a selection from tables related using a many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to sql, I've looked at similar questions and answers on the platform, but still couldn't solve my problem.

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CartProducts (
    Id        PRIMARY KEY
    ProductId int
    Quanity   int
)

CREATE TABLE  CartCartProducts ( /* <-- many to many table */
    CartProductsId PrimaryKey
    CartId         PrimaryKey
)

CREATE TABLE Cart (
    Id     PrimaryKey
    UserId int
)
```

Before the query I have the following data:

- I know the `UserId`
- I know the `ProductId`
- I know the `CartId`

I need to get the user's product with the passed product's id and user's id

I tried this:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    cart_products cp
    JOIN cart_cart_products cm2m1 ON cm2m1.cart_id = %d 
    INNER JOIN cart_cart_products cm2m2 ON cm2m2.cart_products_id = cp.id
```

I know that using * is not recommended, I will remake it in the future

Comment: `%d` is a C `printf`-style placeholder - you should be using proper query parameters instead (e.g. due to parameterized cached query plan reuse).

Comment: So... what's the problem with the query you tried? Does it work or not? If it doersn't work then what problem are you having with it?

Comment: so you know everything why doy you need another query, joinig tables is need to get a user carts products list, but you say that you have that, besides your query lags that you need to join all three tables

Comment: @nbk In my application, many users can have the same product, the difference is only in its quantity, so when I get the user id, I need to find the product that belongs to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you always have to join all tables. with their columns, after that you have access to all columns and can extract all information needed.

the use of placehoder and parpameters, i omitted, as i don't know which langua you are using, but a quick search should find you a lot of answers

Following query fund you the quantity of a cart with number 1 of userid 1 and of the product 1

Fromhere you have all possibility, to search for all cart of a user, or all products he purchased

```
SELECT 
    cp.Quanity
FROM
    cart_products cp
    JOIN cart_cart_products cm2m1 ON cm2m1.cart_id = cp.iId
    INNER JOIN cart c = c.Id = cm2m1.CartId
WHERE c.UserId  = 1 AND c.id = 1 AND cp.ProductId = 1
```